# How to view events per user/session in Google Analytics dashboard?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics-events

I've added custom segments of the users that did the specified event category. However, I can't view simultaneously number of users and number of events on the same dashboard, which should have been an essential feature.

If anyone has experienced this, please specify how it's possible.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the kind of dashboard widget you're hoping to set up? Adding an example (with fake numbers is fine) would be very helpful.

Comment: @Reve this is the closest to what I want to achieve: https://i.imgur.com/ajTRMVo.png
We have 3 voting options on our website, and ideally I should be able to see both vote type per user, and votes per user in general.